# Add/Share code in comment section to someone else's question

Tags: discussion

Recently I had asked one question on SharePoint Stack exchange. After digging up for 1-2 days I managed to resolve my query. So I share the solution and marked it as an answer.

Now there is one another user who has similar kind of issue(let say user is  `User1`).

Now instead of asking another question, `User1` commented on my question mentioning the same issue. I want this user to share his/her code so that I can have a better understanding of actual problem.

I just want to know, what is the way to share the code in comment section?

Comment: If it's a slightly different issue, ask him/her to open a new thread. Otherwise, it may be best in chat.

Answer (score 4):

As per my comment:

If it's a slightly different issue, ask him/her to open a new thread. Otherwise, it may be best in chat.